# Wallpaper should change automatically on Android phone every day

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I want to make a service which can set wallpaper every day on the Android device Home Screen.
How can we do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for Change Wallpaper programmatically you need following setps in Activity or Service:

**Step 1**:AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses -permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

**Step 2**: in Activity or Service

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.wallpaper);
Bitmap wallpaper = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
```

**Step 3**:

use AlarmManager  for Changeing Wallpaper everyday

Answer (score 2):

The following code changes the home screen wall paper. Run you service when date changes as per your requirement.

WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.setBitmap(myBitmap);